# add host to etc/hosts in a docker windows container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker-network

Since the `extra_hosts:` option in my *docker-compose.yml* is not working, I'm trying to manipulate the *etc/hosts* file in my running windows container.

```
cd C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
echo 192.168.x.x testdomain > hosts
```

The console returns:

> **Access is denied.**

How can I manipulate the *hosts* file, during startup/runtime/build? Maybe the `extra_hosts:` is not working because of "access denied"?

**Setup:**

- Windows 10, 2004
- Docker version: 19.03.12
- image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1903

Comment: [How can I add DNS entries to hosts file of a Windows Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63880160/3110834)

Comment: Maybe try "become: yes" below your service statement in the compose file. "services: container: become: yes"